# How to get a Factory + AOP working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, aop, factory

I have a singleton Spring bean (and it has to stay a singleton) which needs a fresh instance of another bean (Lets call it X) every time a certain method executes.

So far I looked at the following approaches:

- just create X using new. This worked for a while but now we need spring AOP features for X, so this doesn't work anymore, since the resulting instances are not Spring managed.
- I considered a FactoryBean as a dependency, but I would only get a single X instance from the FactoryBean, which doesn't meet my first instance.
- the current plan is to manually lookup X in the Spring context, and declare it there with a prototype dependency. This should work, but I think it is really ugly.

=> How can I inject a factory in my bean so that I can call its factory method any time I see fit and getting a spring managed instance out of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The means of choice for a scenario like this is called [lookup method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection). In short, this uses the approach of a call to a bean method resulting in a new bean instance created. You'd start by creating a class with an abstract method that will eventually provide the dependency instance:

```
abstract class MyClient implements Client {

  void businessMethod(…) {

    Dependency dependency = getDependencyInstance();
    …
  }

  abstract Dependency getDependencyInstance();
}
```

You now go ahead and configure a prototype bean definition for the dependency:

```
<bean id="dependency" class="….DependencyImpl" scope="prototype" />
```

As well as the client using the `lookup-method` element to always get a fresh instance of the dependency for each method call:

```
<bean class="….MyClient">
  <lookup-method name="getDependencyInstance" bean="dependency" />
</bean>
```

This will cause a CGLib proxy being created for `MyClient` and the method declaration of `getDependencyInstance(…)` being backed by a `TargetSource` with a reference to the `BeanFactory` and the name of the bean to be looked up. On each method invocation the bean lookup will be triggered and a fresh instance of the prototype configured bean is returned.

Comment: I use this technique in my own code; it works pretty well. The only down-side is that the class containing it is abstract, which reduces the amount of support that your IDE is likely to provide for filling in methods that are declared in other interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem with the factory bean and i'd do it like so:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class X {
    public static class XFactory implements FactoryBean<X> {

        @Override
        public X getObject() throws Exception {
            return new X();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return X.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

and inject this factory bean.

Otherwise you can scope your X bean with

```
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

You must use a non default proxy mode so that spring creates a proxy that always returns a new instance to your singleton.

If you're on XML config than do it like so:

```
<bean id="x" class="X" scope="prototype">
<aop:scoped-proxy>
</bean>
```

Have fun.

Edit:

When you annotate your factory through @Component (i've added it above), return false in #isSingleton and make sure your don't return your X twice you can inject the factory bean with @Autowired into your singleton.

Otherwise i've just checked

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class X {
}
```

it works as expected.

Edit 2:

If you don't want to inject the factory bean but just want to inject the dependency you can prototype scope your factory (@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="prototype")) but than a new factory is created everytime X is involved which is probably not what you want.

If you don't want the factory itself injected i'd go with Olivers lookup method.

Comment: But wouldn't I get a single X instance inside my dependent clas A? My understanding was that if I inject a FactoryBean I only get an instance of the type parameter of the FactoryBean not the FactoryBean itself?

Comment: yes you are correct, you only will get a different instance of the bean if you ask another one from your application context, so make a factory, make it implement ApplicationContextAware (i think it's called that) and give it a getX() method calling applicationcontext.getbean(X.class), and declare X as a prototype. Or something along those lines

Comment: Jens: You can just inject a factory bean like any other bean and call it's method directly.

Comment: @MichaelSimons I think the resulting beans wouldn't be spring managed? I guess I have to do some experiments.

Comment: @G-Man thats what I referred to as a manual lookup in the question. Should work, but not really nice.

Comment: it's not nice but i don't think there is another option